# Push array into Nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some code like this:

```
var array=[[[[[[1],2],3],4],5],6]
```

I know how to retrieve the innermost array, but I don't know how to push a new array [0] into the innermost array.

---

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the practical use of this?  FYI, whatever strategy you use for reading the inner value of `1`, you can just assign another array to that same reference.

Comment: What is your desired output?  What have you tried?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is making an organized array system with sub-arrays that makes it easier to acheive certain things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to add new inner-most array on the first position. You can use unshift function:

```
array[0][0][0][0][0].unshift([0]);
```

Comment: It says I can accept an answer in 5 min. In the meantime, I tried the code and you seem to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var array=[[[[[[1],2],3],4],5],6];
function pushNew(arr, newElement){
  if(arr[0].length === 2){
    pushNew(arr[0], newElement);
  } else {
    arr[0].unshift([newElement]);
  }
}
pushNew(array,0);
```